# config.h file not found

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am working on thr react-native platform. I am using iOS. After creating project, the following error found:

> config.h file not found mutex.h

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: What version of react native? Is it a clean install (with no third party modules)?

Comment: Try this [solution](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14382#issuecomment-313163119)

Comment: react native version 0.56.0 and i use realm module for database  .

Answer (score 1):

The solution works for me is:

- Quit your Xcode
- Navigate to

  `cd node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4/`
- Then execute command:

  `./configure && make && make install`
- Now open project in Xocde, Build and Run.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following commands in the project directory. Helped me resolve my *config.h not found* issue

1. cd node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4/
2. ./configure
3. make
4. make install
5. cd ../../../..
6. react-native run-ios